# 'New' Register names in nasm

Tags: nasm, x86-64, cpu-registers

According to this resource (http://www.sandpile.org/x86/gpr.htm), it seems that with expanding to 64 bit cpus, existing registers (rax - rdi) were given alternate names (R0 - R7) to be consistent with the names of the new registers (R8 - R15).

If I try to use these 'newer' names though, NASM just says Symbol Undefined.

Are these names actually in use? If so, what compiler recognizes them (looking though options of nasm didn't indicate any flags for using them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you meant by "compiler" in this case.

The nasm documentation mentions the `altreg` "standard macro", is that what you're looking for?  http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.04/html/nasmdoc5.html#section-5.1

Comment: Compiler/Interpreter/Assembler. The thing that takes asm instructions and turns them into byte code. What is it actually called?

Comment: @Shade I'd say it's assembler, or translator if you will. But I asked anyways because I had not had enough coffee yet  :-)